# How to read files from android asset folder in a HTML file?

Tags: android, html

I am making a HTML based app for android. I displayed the html file by this: `"file:///android_asset/index.html"`

But I want to load local image file or font in that html file and I have loaded them in the asset folder.

Doing this as source link do not work.

```
<img src="file:///android_asset/p100.jpg" style="width:85px">
```

So, how do I use local asset files in my html so that it shows them in my app?

Comment: You may have better luck loading the image from a "relative" location: simply `src="p100.jpg"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your assets folder must have the name "assets", since it is mapped this way.

> file:///android_asset/ => "assets" folder

PLUS: if you load your `WebView` data like this

```
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", html, "text/html; charset=UTF-8", null, null);
```

your img tag turns into this

```
<img src="p100.jpg" style="width:85px">
```

since the base url becomes your assets folder.